# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{B_{2n}}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(e-1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, bernoulli-numbers

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{B_{2n}}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(e-1)^2}$$
My idea is to find the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(e^x-1)^2}$, but it seems not useful.

Any helps, thanks

Comment: What is your definition of the Bernoulli numbers $B_{2n}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exponential [generating function of Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function) is given by
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n{x^n\over n!}={x\over e^x-1}\\
$$
which upon differentiation gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n{x^{n-1}\over(n-1)!}={e^x-1-xe^x\over (e^x-1)^2}
$$
Plugging in $x=\pm 1$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {B_n\over(n-1)!}=-{1\over(e-1)^2},\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^nB_n\over(n-1)!}={(e-2)e\over(e-1)^2}
$$
Adding these up we get
$$
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_{2n}\over{(2n-1)!}}=1-{2\over(e-1)^2}
$$

Comment: good stuff (+1)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/BernoulliB/07/01/01/)

$$ B_{2n} = (-1)^{n}4n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \, dx.$$

Specifically,

$$ \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n-1)!} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)!} (-1)^{n-1} 4n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \, dx \\ &= 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n (-1)^{n-1}   x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} \, dx. \end{align}$$

But notice that $$ \begin{align} \sin (x) + x \cos(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!} \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{[1+(2n-1)](-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}. \end{align}$$

So using the fact that [$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \, \coth \left(\frac{a}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2a},   $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366437/contour-integration-to-compute-int-0-infty-frac-sin-axe2-pi-x-1-mat)   we get

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n-1)!} &= 2 \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \,dx +  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos x}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \, dx \right] \\ &= 2  \left[\frac{1}{4} \, \coth \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \left(\frac{1}{4} \, \coth \left(\frac{a}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2a}\right)\Bigg|_{a=1}  \right]  \\ &= 2 \left[\frac{1}{4} \, \coth \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8} \, \text{csch}^{2}  \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \right] \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \, \coth \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{4} \, \text{csch}^{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \\&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{e+1}{e-1} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{4e}{(e-1)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{(e^{2}-1) -2e}{2(e-1)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{(e-1)^{2}-2}{2(e-1)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{(e-1)^{2}}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the identity $$x\cot\left(x\right)-1=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B_{2n}\left(-4\right)^{n}x^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!},\,\left|x\right|<\frac{\pi}{2}
 $$ so taking the derivative and manipulating a bit $$x\cot\left(x\right)-\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B_{2n}\left(-4\right)^{n}x^{2n}}{\left(2n-1\right)!}
 $$ hence taking $x=\frac{i}{2}
 $ we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{B_{2n}}{\left(2n-1\right)!}=\frac{i\cot\left(i/2\right)}{2}+\frac{1}{4\sin^{2}\left(i/2\right)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\left(e-1\right)^{2}}.$$