# Real integral with residue method and infinite singularities

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$I=\int_0^\infty{\sin(ax)\over e^{2\pi x}-1}dx $$
I extend to the complex plane, so i have: $ f(z)={e^{iaz}\over e^{2\pi z}-1}$. The singularities are in $ z= ik,  k\in  \mathbb{Z}$.
$$ \lim_{z \to ik}{e^{iaz}\over e^{2\pi z}-1}=\infty$$ so the singularities are poles (I'm not sure if this is correct), and :$$ \lim_{z \to ik}{e^{iaz}(z-ik)\over e^{2\pi z}-1}=\frac{e^{-ak}}{2\pi} $$
This proves that they are simple poles and the residue in $ik$ is $\frac{e^{-ak}}{2\pi}$. Now I don't know what integration path should I take, since the integral is from zero to infinity.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366437/contour-integration-to-compute-int-0-infty-frac-sin-axe2-pi-x-1-mat/366540#366540